# obtengo el error LNK1561

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a diseñar clases y he encontrado un archivo fuente del libro **"C++ for C programmers"** en el que se hace una implemenatción elemental para números complejos (ya sé que existe el tipo **complex** en la **STL**, pero lo que me interesa es aprender a diseñar clases elementales); el caso es que el *linker* me da el error **LNK1561**, como si me hubiera olvidado la función `main`...

```
// An elementary implementation of type complex
#include <iostream>      //IO library
#include <string>        //string type

using namespace std;

class complex {
public:                   //universal access to interface

   void re_assign(double r) { real = r; }
   void im_assign(double im) { imaginary = im; }
   void print() const
   {
     cout << "(" << real << ","
          << imaginary << "i)" << endl;
   }

   friend complex operator+(complex, complex);

private:                  //restricted access to implementation

   double real, imaginary;

};

//overload +
complex operator+(complex x, complex y)
{
   complex t;
   t.real = x.real + y.real;
   t.imaginary = x.imaginary + y.imaginary;
   return t;
}

int main()
{
   complex x, y, z;
   x.re_assign(9.5);
   x.im_assign(-4.5);
   y.re_assign(4.2);
   y.im_assign(6.0);

   z = x + y;
   x.print();
   y.print();
   z.print();

   int look; cin >> look;
}
```

Comment: Estás planteando dos cosas muy distintas; si has resuelto la primera (`error LNK1561`) podrías aclararlo y después poner una pregunta independiente sobre la segunda (`sobrecargar operadores`).

Comment: No he resuelto nada :(  si es necesario separaré las preguntas, pero la segunda parte es otra implementación...

Comment: ¿El código está dividido en dos o más ficheros? Si es así (que no lo se porque no lo indicas) es posible que al linker no le estés pasando todos los ficheros.

Comment: Ojalá fuera eso pero es solo un fichero...

Comment: Descargué un ejemplo que constaba de un solo  .cpp pero imagino que el autor usó un editor diferente, acabo de probar que si pico línea por línea con un archivo creado por mi editor entonces el programa compila y al ejecutar se comporta de la manera esperada, pero sigo sin entender que tendría que cambiar en el archivo descargable para compilarlo en visual studio.

Comment: Entiendo que os ha dado el mismo error...

Comment: Puedes comenzar con https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620919.aspx

Comment: @JoseAntonioMartinezEscobedo. No es que nos haya dado el mismo error... si no nos etiquetas en tu comentario no nos aparece un aviso y no nos enteramos de que estás escribiendo comentarios nuevos.

Comment: Analizando tu comentario, entiendo que el error es por algún caracter no imprimible que se ha colado en el fichero... prueba a editarlo con `notepad++` y activa la visualización de caracteres no imprimibles... a ver si aparece algo que no sean saltos de línea y retornos de carro.